# A variable that is not public or private-Java

Tags: java, variables, private, public

Hello fellow programmers,

If a variable is defined not to be a public or private defined outside the method
such as:

```
Graphics    goff;
  Image     ii;
  Thread    thethread;
```

what would the variable be defined as?

Comment: I meant "outside the method". Edited Post. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

The variables as defined without any explicit modifier would have an access level of `package-private`. These variables can only be accessed within its own package. You can read more about access/variable scope levels for java [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: so is it basically defined as a private instance variable in the  default package that the .java file is currently in?

Comment: Thanks very much everyone for the replies!